GStreamer`s m3u8 playlist segment names
Why does GStreamer create m3u8 playlist with full segment filenames?
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3

#EXTINF:3.4609496593475342,
C:\Users\user\Desktop\4\stream0.ts
#EXTINF:3.0114498138427734,
C:\Users\user\Desktop\4\stream1.ts

but I need only
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3

#EXTINF:3.4609496593475342,
stream0.ts
#EXTINF:3.0114498138427734,
stream1.ts

How can I specify this to gst?
When I specify relative path in location or playlist-location, segments and playlist are created in the root folder. Playlist anyway contains full filename paths

I've found solution. Don't need to specify playlist-root parameter
